# Remove ansi-escape-sequences from string while still honoring them

Tags: ruby, string, io, ansi-escape

If I have a string with ansi escape sequences, when I print them to the terminal they can move the cursor around for me so I end up with the following:

```
puts "xxx\nxxx\nxxx\n\e[2Fbe\e[2E"

# terminal sees
xxx
bex
xxx

##    
# breakdown of "xxx\nxxx\nxxx\n\e[2Fbe\e[2E"

# 1st, the "xxx\nxxx\nxxx\n" is printed
xxx
xxx
xxx
*

# then with `\e[2F` the cursor is moved up 2 lines
xxx
*xx


# then `be` is printed
xxx
bex

# then the cursor is returned to the bottom with `\e[2F`
xxx
bex
xxx
*
```

How do I write a method to encode the string as this final output. This method needs to be more sophisticated than just stripping the escape sequences out - as they actually need to have an effect on the final string.

In other words, how do I write `some_magic` to give me this kind of output for arbitrary input string.

```
x = my_method(""xxx\nxxx\nxxx\n\e[2Fbe\e[2E"")
#=> "xxx\nbex\nxxx"
```

Comment: why not `foo` ? why not `bar\ncat"` ? I am asking to understand the logic.. :)

Comment: how `\n` come at last ?

Comment: Is the string *fixed length* ?

Comment: @sawa Tested in console, doing the escape sequence in my head was a bad idea :).

Comment: @sawa The basic idea here is to get the result of string _without_ caret movements.

Comment: *caret movements* means ?

Comment: @sawa Thanks... *OP* - Is the string fixed length ?

Comment: @sawa I could calculate the length ahead of time (if that helps the implementation), but for this case consider the input string any valid string

Comment: Why is `"bar\n"` gone?

Comment: Would this `s = "foo\nbar\n\e[2Acat"
s.unpack('@12A3') # => ["cat"]` work ?

Comment: @sawa I'm not sure actually. I originally thought they would be there (which is why I had them in the question) but when I fired up the console to try it out bar is gone. My test could be wrong, but I also made an executable script with the simple `puts` line and that too didn't output `bar\n`. Does your test differ? I frankly would expect `bar\n` to remain.

Comment: Or this `s.unpack('@4A4x4A3').join # => "bar\ncat"` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit can you explain more about what you're doing there? I don't know what `@12A3`. I need all caret movements to be played out and I can't tell if that will do that for me.

Comment: @thedeeno Atlast you responded my questions? :-) see this http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-unpack

Comment: @ArupRakshit only allowed to comment every 15 seconds, these comments came in fast. Anyways, why not post as answer so I can upvote if it works out?

Comment: Also if either of you downvoted it'd be nice if you could retract, since I haven't gotten a single view since then...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49436/discussion-between-thedeeno-and-arup-rakshit)

Comment: I am not getting, what *magic* you are looking for.. until we understand *magic*/*logic*, we can't help for you...